# Problems with eagerly loading constraints in Laravel 4 - a workaround?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 tables, Places and Users. Places can have many Users.

```
// in Place.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}

//in User.php
public function place()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Place');
}
```

and am trying to get only the Places that have at least one active and enabled User associated through a static method Place::locationsWithPeople().

```
public static function locationsWithPeople()
{
     return Place::with(array('users' => function($query)
        {
            $query->where('enabled', '=', 1)->where('active', '=', 1);
        }))->get();
}
```

This yields an HTTP 500. Removing the two wheres does not help.

This works, but of course it does not contain the two wheres:

```
    return Place::has('users')->get();
```

Anyone can help? It seems totally analogous to the example in Laravel's documentation.

Comment: What's the error message that comes with the 500 error? Does it show the mysql query generated? Lastly, have you checked out [scoping](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes)?

Comment: Ciao @fideloper , I just cleaned the logs and checked; it seems that the query eats up more than 128 MB of ram. I hadn't looked into that since it seems strange it uses that much.

Comment: It's still more valuable to us to be able to see the error message and any query info it may have in it. Is the error just a PHP error of too much memory used?

Comment: seems so. This is what I have in the logs:
    [07-Jul-2013 22:56:25 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 50 bytes) in /media/sf_laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php on line 5376

Comment: ... btw, if you know of a way to dd the query that Eloquent produces , it'd be much appreciated :)

Comment: Tried to up the memory to 256MB. It still fails but this time I get a screen error - now it dies while converting to JSON. It does seem that code is correct and the issue is with resource usage.
Either way, it seems way too much, especially since it is much more economic and fast when not placing additional conditions; I'll open a github issue and see if there may be some workarounds.
Thanks for your help, @fideloper

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
$place = new Place;

$array = $place->with(array('users' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('enabled', 1)->where('active', 1);
}))->get();

var_dump($array->toArray());
```

Maybe because you are trying to use non-static methods statically?

Comment: Hi @The Shift Exchange, no, I can confirm it is just a resource usage issue. I upped the resources (to 512MB ...) and it works. I cannot afford to use that many resources though, so I rewrote the code using joins, etc. Now it is way faster too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was caused by excessive resource consumption, leading the page to HTTP500 over resource exhaustion. Fixed by rewriting it through join statements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
return Place::with(array('users' => function($query)
        {
            $query->where('enabled', '=', 1)->where('active', '=', 1);
        }))->hasWith('users')->get();
```

Method hasWithis a scope that written by me. You can get scopeHasWith() from http://paste.laravel.com/13jb. This will work same as has() method but it will call eagerload closure before attach WHERE to query builder.

I think this can resolve your problem that used resource too much and you can WHERE them from eagerload closure. I had same problem as you that I want to query with relation but it send all records that match WHEREIN too and cause memory problem.